# How to fix this strange behavior with BootStrap's responsive design?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My website is using BootStrap templates to automate responsive design when used on mobile devices. The [home](http://people.rit.edu/jnp5028/260/index.html) and [about](http://people.rit.edu/jnp5028/260/about.html) page has some problems with responsive design.

**HOME and ABOUT page (viewed on Desktop):**

The home and about page will display correctly in the Desktop Browser Window and I shrinked the window to test its responsive design and it works, showing an iconbar that's clickable and slides more navigation links.

[image: BrowserWin]

**HOME and ABOUT page (viewed on Mobile):**

Now, one thing that bothers me is the iconbar seen in the previous image isn't there when viewed in the mobile browser and insteads lists all the navigations under the navbar as if it's a desktop. The home page viewed on mobile stays responsive will the navigations links all out.

[image: MobileBrowser]

Even more baffling is when I refresh the page, there's no navigation list, no iconbar and then it becomes responsive in the mobile browser.

[image: MobileBrowser2]

And so, I keep refreshing and it goes back and forth like the last two images. I want to know how to approach this problem and make it correct and consistently responsive as seen in the Desktop Browser Window.

**NOTE: Feel free to view source or inspect at the links provided at the beginning of my question and copy/paste code as needed to figure out the problem I'm having. Thanks!**

** external CSS (custom styles applied to both pages)**

```
@import url("bootstrap.min.css");
@import url("bootstrap-theme.css");

.jumbotron{
  margin-top: 50px;
 background-color:transparent;
background-size: cover;
color: #FFFFFF;
} 

.jumbotron h1{
color: #FFFFFF;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #888888;
} 

.row{
margin: 0 auto;
}

.row img{
height:300px;
width:300px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.full {
  background: url("../images/laser_keyboard.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

body, .container{
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

**embedded CSS (about.html)**

```
    @import url("bootstrap.min.css");
    @import url("bootstrap-theme.css");

    .container{
        background-color:#fff;
    }

    body{
        margin-top: 30px;
    }

    footer{
        margin: 10px 0;
    }
```

Comment: It works as expected in my phone (Nokia N9).

Comment: @azeós can you describe what you see on both pages? Were you able to use an iconbar to navigate the links or were they already present like shown above or none shown?

Comment: @NeerajKumar I added the css code above.

Comment: can you tell us which phone and which browser you used to test where you found the problem. Coz, in chrome browser of my phone (sony android) it seems to work as shown in 1st image.

Comment: I see exactly what it shows the first image. I click in the iconbar and I see all the links.

Comment: @ds345 I am using Windows Phone 8, Nokia Lumia 1020 using Internet Explorer.

Comment: I had the opportunity to test the website on mobile devices. It works perfectly on iPhone (Safari), Android (Chrome) But the round images are squared which I have to change to make round for chrome, and lastly IE is f***** up, lol. But thanks for your feedback guys, I appreciate it, I'm try and go back to my code and do some adjusting to fit all browsers. IE is messed up big time on mobile display however, perfectly displayed on the desktop's IE.